# How to get each flavors prices for each datacenter

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, infrastructure

i'm using softlayer python sdk,

i could get flavor's general VM price using getCreateObjectOptions()

how to get the prices for each datacenter?

here is my code:

```
    import SoftLayer
    import pprint
    client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username="", api_key="")
    flavor = client['Virtual_Guest'].getCreateObjectOptions()
    pprint.pprint(flavor)
```

Comment: share some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: You should update your answer. don't share code in comments

Answer (score 0):

That depends of the items that you want to order, the getCreateObjectOptions() method displays only standard prices, you can see more about Standard prices here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you

In order to see how much is going to cost the VM in a Datacenter you need to pick out all the items that you want in your VM, then you can use the method:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/generateOrderTemplate

This method will generate an orderData this orderData you must send it to the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

The method will return the pricing information of your VM, then you can use the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/

to order the new VM.